# Can I put a GPL licensed binary file in my proprietary software?

Tags: gpl, gpl-2

The source code of this binary is under GPL V2. In my software, I didn't use its code, I just execute this binary to do some tasks, nothing more. Is it legal?

Comment: Have you read [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7078/is-it-legal-to-use-gpl-code-in-a-proprietary-closed-source-program-by-putting-i/7080#7080)?

Comment: If you distribute a GPL program (as a binary) then one obligation of the GPL is that you also must distribute the source code.